# Binding to enums

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there a way to bind a combobox to an enum, since there are no methods to get all the values of enums?

My enum is like this:

```
public enum SportName
{
    [Display(Name = "football", Description = "Football")]
    Football,

    [Display(Name = "table-tennis", Description = "Table Tennis")]
    TableTennis

}
```

I have a method that is retrieving the attributes.
My problem is how to bind these values to a ComboBox and the combobox shoul display the Description for each item.

For me, finding a way to iterate through the enum and creating some kind of a list would be enough but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059036/

Comment: I'm not getting deep into the topic, but I stumbled upon an article on exactly this topic recently: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/03/binding-to-enum-in-windows-8.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(SportName)) // returns string[]
```

or

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(SportName)) // returns int[]
```

Comment: I think you swapped the return types there. GetNames should be the one returning `string[]` :)

Comment: `GetValues` actually returns all the members of the enum, so it's `Enum[]`, which is convertible to and from an `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is from my `EnumComboBox` class, which inherits from `ComboBox`

```
public Type EnumType { get; private set; }
public void SetEnum<T>(T defaultValue) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    SetEnum(typeof(T));
    this.Text = (defaultValue as Enum).GetLabel();
}
public void SetEnum<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    SetEnum(typeof(T));
}
private void SetEnum(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsEnum)
    {
        EnumType = type;
        ValueMember = "Value";
        DisplayMember = "Display";
        var data = Enum.GetValues(EnumType).Cast<Enum>().Select(x => new
        {
            Display = x.GetLabel(), // GetLabel is a function to get the text-to-display for the enum
            Value = x,
        }).ToList();
        DataSource = data;
        this.Text = data.First().Display;
    }
    else
    {
        EnumType = null;
    }
}

public T EnumValue<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (typeof (T) != EnumType) throw new InvalidCastException("Can't convert value from " + EnumType.Name + " to " + typeof (T).Name);

    return (T)this.SelectedValue;
}
```

You can't set it at design-time, but when you initalize the box you can just call

```
myCombo.SetEnum<SportName>();
```

and then later to get the value

```
var sport = myCombo.EnumValue<SportName>();
```